# Maven system variables

Tags: variables, maven, command-line, command, system

When I wanted to enable Maven to run from the command line, I did the following things:

Installation directory:

```
C:\Software\maven221
```

System Variables (not user variables):

```
M2_HOME: C:\Software\maven221

M2: %M2_HOME%\bin
Path: ......;%M2%
```

The location of the JDK is also in the Path variable.

When I execute: `java -version` from cmd, it gives me the correct response.

When I execute: `mvn --version` it says it can not find mvn as a command.

Comment: M2 and Path being 2 different variables ofcourse

Comment: Have you restarted your command window? The environment settings will only affect newly created/started applications.

Comment: Yes, even logged off and in again

Comment: So if you call `set path` in a command window, how is the `%M2%` resolved? Can you see the correct path to maven in the resolved path expression?

Comment: If I call `set path` it resolves `%M2%` as `C:\Software\maven\bin`

Comment: And is that correct? Shouldn't it be `C:\Software\maven221\bin`?

Comment: I changed it from 'maven221' to 'maven', so that should be the correct path yes

Comment: Does it make a difference if I put certain variables with the user variables instead of the system variables? Or should it work with everything in system variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the `M2` environment variable is of any use by maven.

Just create this environment variable:

```
set M2_HOME = C:\Software\maven221
```

And add to the PATH like this:

```
set PATH = %M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I changed it like this, but still the mvn command is not recognised.

Comment: And put it as system variables, not user variables.

Comment: They are in the system variables. It's maven 2.2.1 that I use, if that should make a difference, in a Win7 environment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Maven but in my config I have `M2` and `M2_HOME` in the user variables, not in the system variables.

Here is what I have in the user variables :

```
M2 : %M2_HOME%\bin

M2_HOME : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31

PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME and PATH are in the system variables then?

Comment: Nop, I didn't want to mess up the real "Path" in the system variables, so I put all those variables in the user. I don't know if it's the correct way but it does work.